# Remove all the non words except quote in regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following:

```
string = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]]", ' ', string)
```

This works to remove all the non words. Now I would like to do almost the same but keep the single quotes in my string this time. How do I need to change my regex?

Example: Queen's son is sleeping, but he will wake up.

Result: queen's son is sleeping but he will wake up

Comment: Add `'` to the class - `[^A-Za-z']`

Comment: typo or are you using this: `]]` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the single quote escaped in your group:

```
([^A-Za-z\'])
```

Including it in your example:

```
string = re.sub("[^A-Za-z\']", ' ', string)
```

Edit: You don't need to escape single quote so:

```
string = re.sub("[^A-Za-z']", ' ', string)
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the single quote here.